# SELECT WHERE Date is equal to what user typed not working

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to get the user to type a date and make PHP display records who's date (date type field) is equal to the date the user entered. I keep getting zero results when it should at least show 1.

Here's my current code. Note that I had to fill something in case the user leaves the date text box empty (in case he doesn't want to search by date)

`$Query = 'SELECT fname,lastname FROM recordsdb WHERE joindate = ?';`

and the section:

```
$Bind_fdate = date("Y-m-d");
if ($_POST["userinputdate"] != "enterdatehere") {$Bind_fdate = strtotime($_POST["userinputdate"]);}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$Bind_fdate);
```

I am only showing the needed parts but this code works until I added the date comparison part of it. I just need to display records who's dates matches the date the user types in. The joindate field in database is a date type field (YYYY-MM-DD) like `2015-07-21`. There's no date type in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` so I used `s`. Even if the user types `2015-07-21` or `2015-7-21` I get zero result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just convert both dates in where clause to same format

Answer (score 0):

could be a problem related to date_format

```
 "SELECT fname,lastname FROM recordsdb WHERE joindate = date_format(? , '%Y-%m-%d')";
```

Answer (score 0):

The strtotime() function will return an epoch, not the formatted date that you need.

Try replacing

> strtotime($_POST["userinputdate"])

With

> date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["userinputdate"]))

You also won't need the first line any further.